# Retrieve Rails flash data from AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, local-storage, session-storage

In my rails app, in a controller, I need to flash data like so

`flash[:some_data] = {a: 'dfdfsf', b: 'xcxsdsd}`

when I save a record.

However in my app, this page redirects to an AngularJS page and I need to read the flash data from the AngularJS page.

How can I send flash data from Rails to Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can do redirect by window.location and render the flash data as JSON in rails controller to the AngularJS page.

Then you can use [toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) plugin to fetch the JSON flash data and display it from AngularJs controller. For example, the success message toastr will be below:

toaster.pop('success', "Success", response.some_data)